# Switch the Odd Ones 7 (Very Advanced)

Tags: pattern, odd-one-out

[image: OOO7]

Two similar but independent patterns has gotten one out of nine parts misplaced with the other pattern. What two figures (one in range a-i and the other in range 1-9) are the odd ones that should be switched to restore both patterns, and why?

*Created by myself*

Comment: With the `odd-one-out` tag and some other tag not in the top 50 most used tags, you could have entered this in the [**Fortnightly Topic Challenge #37**](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6389/fortnightly-topic-challenge-37-rare-and-endangered-1) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it

> **e and 9?**

Rationale:

> I notice that taking each shape separately, they are reflected diagonally topleft-bottomright. So that suggests that the two squares that we need to swap are along the diagonal. Then I looked at the bottom diamond. I notice that swapping e and 9 results in this shape alternating + and x on both grids.

Comment: Great! You got it! :)